# Why do TV Shows take mid-season breaks?

Tags: analysis, production, distribution

Serials like *The Flash*, *Arrow*, and *Agents of SHIELD* are now in a mid season break.

1. What does it mean?
2. Why do they take break in series like this?

Comment: Related [Why do broadcasters have a mid-season break in TV season?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70747/why-do-broadcasters-have-a-mid-season-break-in-tv-season) ?

Answer (score 2):

Throughout the television season, shows frequently take breaks, It’s particularly common in the winter months around the holidays for shows to take an extended break, leaving reruns in their place. **This is called hiatus.**

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(television)),

> In American English the term hiatus may be used to refer to a break of
>   several weeks or months in the normal broadcast programming of a
>   television series in the United States. Such a break can occur
>   part-way through the season of a series, in which case it is called a
>   mid-season break, or between distinct television seasons (usually
>   starting in June and ending in September, when shooting starts for the
>   next season). On the Northern Hemisphere, the breaks between
>   late-November and early-February are also referred to as winter breaks
>   or, in the Christian cultural-sphere, Christmas breaks.

It could be for multiple reasons. Quoting [ScreenerTV](http://screenertv.com/news-features/tv-hiatus-explained-why-your-favorite-shows-take-breaks-during-the-season/)

> he most simple answer is: math. There are about 22 episodes in a
>   typical primetime season on the five major networks. There are 52
>   weeks in a  year. Additionally, it takes more than one week to shoot
>   an episode — your average episode of, say, “The Vampire Diaries” or
>   “Revenge” takes 8 days to shoot, and that’s not counting writing,
>   prep, and post-production. If there were no hiatuses, your season
>   would begin in late September and end at the end of January, and then
>   you’d have to wait 8 months to discover how that cliffhanger turns
>   out.
>
> As with most things in the television industry, what it really comes
>   down to is money. With the exception of premium cable networks, most
>   networks make money off of their television shows by selling
>   advertising. The advertising companies use ratings to decide how much
>   a 30-second commercial is worth during a certain show, based on how
>   many eyes will actually see that commercial.
>
> Though ratings information is collected every week, Nielsen is more
>   thorough in their ratings investigation during “sweeps” periods, which
>   fall roughly in November, February, May, and July. During these
>   four-week periods, Nielsen asks several panels of homes to keep a
>   detailed paper diary of the television they watch, live and via DVR.
>   They analyze what certain demographics are tuned into.
>
> Generally, it’s in the networks’ best interests to make sure their
>   best, most attention-grabbing episodes air during sweeps, because then
>   more Nielsen families will watch, then the networks can sell
>   commercials for more money. That’s why you’ll most often see big-name
>   guest stars or shocking twists during these periods. Shows often go on
>   hiatus right before these breaks so that the networks can save their
>   best episodes for sweeps weeks. Shows return from hiatus with a big
>   promotional push and lots of press right as the advertising companies
>   start paying attention.